# WSL2: ddev sites won't load in a web browser on the Windows side

Tags: windows, ubuntu, local, ddev

I setup ddev, ubuntu 18.04 and wsl2 on windows 10 following the https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ guide
and video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMfHaUkhfc0

Ubuntu 20.04 https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/ubuntu-2004/9n6svws3rx71?rtc=1#activetab=pivot:overviewtab is not available which is what I used before and I can't get it to work I set up a Junk project but I can't get it load in my web browser (chrome) https://junk.ddev.site/ I just get the following message "This site can’t be reached Check if there is a typo in junk.ddev.site.
If spelling is correct, try running windows network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" I added this junk.ddev.site 127.0.0.1 to my host file but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: You most likely have something else running on the required port. Try changing the port you're using (`router_http_port: 8080` and `router_https_port: 8443` in the config.yaml.) It's probably easier to get support for something like this in the [Discord community](https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k)

Comment: I tried changing the port but that didn't work

Comment: I tried this https://junk.ddev.site:8443 after config.yaml file as above. In chrome view site information I get the following message "Your connection to the site is not secure you should not enter any..." no paddlock

Comment: You need to run `mkcert -install` (on both sides) I imagine, and follow the various instructions to make it work. But in the meantime, just use the http URL, for example http://junk.ddev.site:8080 (assuming you used 8080 for the http url). It's tricky to set up so a browser on the Windows side can use https on WSL2 side, but the instructions are at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#windows-wsl2

Comment: Managed to solve my problem for now, I have to add 127.0.0.1 junk.ddev.site to my windows host file, not this way junk.ddev.site 127.0.0.1 as mention above. I didn't have to do this before. the only thing that is different is my internet router. So every time I create a new ddev project I have to update my windows host file.

Comment: When I start a ddev project  ddev start Starting junk...  The hostname junk.ddev.site is not currently resolvable, trying to add it to the hosts file ddev needs to add an entry to your hostfile. You are on WSL2, so should also manually execute 'sudo ddev hostname junk.ddev.site 127.0.0.1' on Windows if you use a Windows browser.
    sudo /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ddev/1.19.1/bin/ddev hostname junk.ddev.site 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

**Option 1 - Run chrome from Ubuntu in WSL2**

**Option 2 - Change the hosts file on the Windows side, Edit line to be: `127.0.0.1  junk.ddev.site`**

I have found both of these to work.

Option 1 works on Windows 11, I have found - See: [Use Google Chrome in Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem Linux](https://scottspence.com/posts/use-chrome-in-ubuntu-wsl) and [Run Linux GUI apps on the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps). GUI apps in WSL2 on Windows 10 is also apparently available, but I haven't yet tried it there: [see How to install Linux GUI apps on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/run-linux-gui-apps-wsl-windows-10/). It works because it avoids the apparent issues of networking between Ubuntu on WSL2 and Windows. It's as if you have an ordinary Linux box running ddev and chrome.

Option 2, I have found works both on Windows 11 and Windows 10.  Edit the Windows equivalent of the `/etc/hosts` file,  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` - this file is present on both Windows 11 and Windows 10. You'll need to run your text editor as Administrator to edit it and if you use a filter in your text editor's File open dialog, set it to All, to find all files not just `.txt` files - `hosts` doesn't have a file extension.

So for you, @hobbsie, the change you'd do in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` would be:

`127.0.0.1 junk.ddev.site`

and if there is already a  line that starts with `127.0.0.1` in `hosts` comment it out to keep it for future but so that it is not active.

Refs:

- https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/3318#issuecomment-948965259 - about editing `hosts` file on Windows side
- https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/3318#issuecomment-1213142259 - includes info and the links about running Chrome inside WSL2.